# How can I make WHERE clause with field from another table in SQL and Django?

Tags: django, sqlite

Here is table in class from django first app called proizvodi:

```
class Meblovi(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Meblovi"

    #OSNOVNI_PODACI
    ime_proizvoda = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    proizvodjac = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="proizvodjac")
    sastav = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="sastav")
    sirina = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="sirina")
    zemlja_porekla = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="zemlja porekla")
    stara_cena = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10,default=795.00)
    nova_cena = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10,default=795.00)
    na_lageru = models.BooleanField()
    rok_isporuke = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="3 dana")
    jedinica_mere = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="po dužnom metru")

    #SLIKE
    glavna_slika = models.ImageField(upload_to='proizvodi/', null=True, blank=True)

    #KARAKTERISTIKE
    vodootporan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vodoodbojan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nezapaljiv = models. BooleanField(default=False)

    #OSTALO
    izdvojeno = models.BooleanField()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.ime_proizvoda
```

Now, here is table from another app:

```
class Podmeblovi(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Meblovi - podvrste"

    #OSNOVNI_PODACI
    model_mebla = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    mebl = models.ForeignKey(Meblovi, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slika = models.ImageField(upload_to='proizvodi/', null=True, blank=True)

    #BOJE
    bela = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    svetlo_siva = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tamno_siva = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    crna = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bez = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    braon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    zuta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    narandzasta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    crvena = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bordo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    svetlo_zelena = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tamno_zelena = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    svetlo_plava = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tamno_plava = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pink = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ljubicasta = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #DIZAJN
    jednobojno = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sareno = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mebl.ime_proizvoda + " " + self.model_mebla
```

So what I want is to make a sql query which returns content from table Podmeblovi(second app) but only if field from table Meblovi (first app) 'vodootporan' is equal to 1. I tried INNER JOIN and it didn't seem to work. Also, i wanted to use RIGHT JOIN but it says that it is not working yet in Django.
My table from second app is connected to the first app table with foreign key. To explain better, first app table is basic default information table for product. So if we have fabrics product named Portland for example, we got child products of it in second app. They are different colours and designs, but the price and other specs are same for them. So how can I solve this problem?

What i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM modeli_meblova_podmeblovi
INNER JOIN "proizvodi_meblovi" ON ("proizvodi_meblovi"."vodootporan" = "meblovi") 
WHERE "proizvodi_meblovi" = 1
```

This had no errors indeed, but in my database I have products checked true for field 'vodootporan', but sql didn't return any model from database.

Just to be clear, I need sql query because I have many filters to integrate with this one. Other filters are from base table, not joined one.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what you tried. But this should work:

```
Podmeblovi.objects.filter(mebl__vodootporan=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, i posted it now in edit :) I actually need a SQL query if possible because I have many filters and I am creating query using strings. When I create final query, I am sending it to html as context and use in loops.